# Drupal 7 taxonomy translation ok but not visible in admin field

Tags: drupal-7, translation, drupal-taxonomy

Just new in Drupal, I've a problem with new taxonomy terms and specially with the translation of them.

I try to find some explanation in stack overflow but I didn't find the solution of my problem.

So, I've an existing site with some terms (taxo). These terms are already used in some contents with a specific field (list of terms) for this node_type (entity).

When I edit/create a content, I can see my new terms but only for the default language. So when I want to translate my content, I can't see the translated new terms and so can't do use my new terms for other languages.

I try :

- Translate the term with the translate button
- Translate the term via the translate interface
- Refresh string, update,...
- flush the cache

Sorry for my English, I hope I'm clear with my explanations.

If somebody could help me, I'll really appreciate.

Thank you.

---

The solution for me was :

/admin/config/regional/i18n/select
I uncheck the "Select taxonomy terms by language" and it seems to work !

My vocabulary was on "Localize".

I hope that it'll help !

Answer (score 0):

How is the language selection configured? Check these settings:

```
  /admin/config/regional/i18n/select
  /admin/config/regional/language/configure
```

It should work. I've just tried.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what kind of configuration must I checked ?
For the first link, select taxonomy terms by language is checked and for the second link, all is checked.

Comment: "Select taxonomy terms by language" should be checked. The other page shows in what order languages are picked. I usually add a URL prefix on my sites to select translation. What is your way of detecting and selecting translation?

Comment: In the first page check settings under the heading "Enable for specific pages" so you dont exclude translations for the admin paths. Not sure what the default settings are.